# how to use flutter(dart) file in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i made the project with flutter using android studio,
and i carried out the coarse "Right click the Project root folder -> Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio." to use some function.

When I open different project, it is opened in existing flutter setting lilke this (photo 2).
[image: photo 2: existing setting. you can see the logo of flutter...]

But when I open that (carried out the practice 'open android module in android studio') project, it is opened in real android studio setting like this(photo1).
[image: photo 1: now setting. you can see the logo of android not flutter]

but i want to use the project in existing setting(like photo2) from now(like photo 1).
i want to use dart file... how can i do?
Flutter is my first coding, so I'm nooblette to using all program.
Please save me. thankyou....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opened the android folder as a project simply close the project and open a new project as root of your fluter project then it will open as a flutter project as you shown in first picture..